# Matlab and lambertw function

Tags: matlab, lambert-w

I have Matlab 7.9.0 (R2009b)
I want use the W lambert function. does someone know if Lambertw is only available to updated version of Matlab ? or if i need to do something before ?
I am not very good with matlab because i learn with Scilab, Maple and python.

I tried with scilab but i can't made the specfun function work.
It's working with python (scipy.special) but i am not as good to solve ode with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lambertw` function is part of MATLAB's symbolic toolbox. Regardless of version, you must have this toolbox installed to use the function.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/lambertw.html